# How can I specify a font in a grammar-specific way in Atom editor?

Tags: markdown, atom-editor

Atom editor is free and great. However, one of my complaints is that Preferences... does not allow grammar-specific or language-specific font setting. Only when editing markdown, I want to use a proportional font, such as Gill Sans and Arial, rather than fixed-width ones, eg. Consolas.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this conversation](https://github.com/atom/language-gfm/issues/69#issuecomment-69736262), you can do it by the following:

1. From menu, select `Atom > Stylesheet...`, and `styles.css` file will appear.
2. Paste the snippet below at the bottom of the `styles.css` file.

   ```
   atom-text-editor[data-grammar="source gfm"],
   atom-text-editor[data-grammar="source gfm"]::shadow {
       font-family: "Gill Sans";
   }
   ```